# How to find out if Amazon Personalize is doing automatic update for the newest Solution Version

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-personalize

I am building a recommendation system using AWS Personalize. I have imported the required data sets with their corresponding schemas, and create a solution and a solution version with the User-Personalization recipe. From the docs, they mentioned that

> With User-Personalization, Amazon Personalize automatically updates the latest model (solution version) every two hours behind the scenes to include new data without creating a new solution version. With each update, Amazon Personalize updates the solution version with the latest item information and adjusts the exploration according to implicit feedback from users. This allows Amazon Personalize to gauge item quality based on new interactions for already explored items and continually update item exploration.

> Amazon Personalize automatically updates only the latest solution version trained with trainingMode set to FULL and only if you provide new item or interactions data since the last automatic update. If you have trained a new solution version, Amazon Personalize will not automatically update older solution versions that you have deployed in a campaign. Updates also do not occur if you have deleted your dataset.

I have created a solution version with the **trainingMode** set to FULL. Currently, I am using bulk import for the new user, items, and interactions datasets, and have created a new import job for all three datasets. And when I checked the solution version status and description after 2 hours using Python SDK, it's not showing that the solution version has been updated. Here is the output of the code when I ran `personalize.list_solution_versions(solutionArn)`

```
{'solutionVersions': [{'solutionVersionArn': 'arn:aws:personalize:us-east-2:848004361486:solution/gh-personalize-solution-beta/1b4b2abe',
   'status': 'ACTIVE',
   'creationDateTime': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 30, 13, 49, 27, 507000, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
   'lastUpdatedDateTime': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 30, 14, 50, 3, 966000, tzinfo=tzlocal())}],
 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '42c08bd5-e13f-4ab4-bd74-5de8521b9a19',
  'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
  'HTTPHeaders': {'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1',
   'date': 'Thu, 01 Jul 2021 12:38:07 GMT',
   'x-amzn-requestid': '42c08bd5-e13f-4ab4-bd74-5de8521b9a19',
   'content-length': '230',
   'connection': 'keep-alive'},
  'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

My question is, how do I know when AWS Personalize will start updating my solution version after I have imported the new user, item, interaction datasets? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Currently the only indication that Personalize is auto-updating your solution version and campaign is on the Personalize service page in the AWS console on the Details tab of the campaign detail view. Note that the auto-update process does not retrain your model. It incorporates new items from your items dataset and impression data from your interactions for cold item exploration. Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation yet or I'd post a screenshot.